# Resizing divs and buttons for different window size

Tags: jquery, css, html, button, resize

I'm trying to find the size of the client-side window,so that I can re-size my divs and buttons accordingly in a server-side .jsp file.

Things are working exactly how I would like in stickyFooter : [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jAE4e/9/)

But when I go to put this code in my .jsp file in eclipse, there is an error as the output in stickyFooter and my webpage are not the same.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong or is there maybe a mistake in my syntax (below)?

Here is my code in my .jsp file:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$( function() ){
function positionScreen() {
    var winHeight = $(window).height();
    var winWidth = $(window).width();
    var heightContent = winHeight;
    var widthContent = winWidth/2;
    var buttonWidth = winWidth/4;
    var buttonHeight= winWidth/10;


    $("#leftContent").height(heightContent);
    $("#leftContent").width(widthContent);        
    $("#rightContent").height(heightContent);        
    $("#rightContent").width(widthContent);
    $(".clickedbutton").width(buttonWidth);
    $(".clickedbutton").height(buttonHeight);

}
$(window).resize(positionScreen);
positionScreen();
});
</script>


<style type="text/css">

div {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;    
}

#leftContent {
min-height:50px; 
background:#d0d020; 
position: absolute;
left: 0%;
top: 10%;
}

#rightConent {
min-height:50px; 
background:#ff90d0; 
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top:10%;
}

.clickedbutton {color:blue; 
                 background-color: yellow;
                 font-size: 150%; 
                 font-family: Arial Black;
                 position: relative;
                 left: 25%;
}   

.button {color:blue; 
        font-size: 150%; 
        font-family: Arial Black;
        position: relative;
        left: 25%;
}

<div id = "leftContent">
<button id="TV1" name= "TV1" class="clickedbutton"> 
<button id="TV1" name= "TV1" class="clickedbutton">
<button id="TV1" name= "TV1" class="clickedbutton">
<button id="TV1" name= "TV1" class="clickedbutton">
</div> 

<div id = "rightContent">    
<button id="TV1" name= "TV1" class="clickedbutton"> 
<button id="TV2" name= "TV2" class="clickedbutton">  
<button id="TV3" name= "TV2" class="clickedbutton">   
<button id="TV3" name= "TV2" class="clickedbutton">        
</div>
```

Comment: I think you can achieve the same thing with css by setting the width using %

Comment: try changing your script tag `<script>` to `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: This should be totally possible with pure CSS. Or did I miss something special? It just looks like percentage-based widths?

Comment: I'm gonna disagree with the pure css call...anytime your dealing with height, css is so inconsistent. Just my 2 cents...

Comment: Use CSS and Media queries. How to do it is left as homework :P

Comment: Ps. Your buttons should be closed `</button>`

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that you don't have the closing `</button>` tag for each of the buttons. Even though the JSFiddle is working, the browser updates the DOM for the incomplete HTML. That may be part of your issue. I'm not familiar with Eclipse, but you can start there. I'd comment, but I don't have enough rep yet.

Comment: let's get you some then ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/jAE4e/13/

The only thing you can't achieve by CSS imho is to define the buttons height based on the window width (if you even did this intentionally).

```
div {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;    
}

#leftContent {
    position: absolute;
    background:#d0d020;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 80%;
}

#rightContent {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%; 
    height: 80%;
    background:#ff90d0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
}

.clickedbutton {
    color:#ff90d0; 
    background-color: yellow;
    font-size: 150%; 
    font-family: Arial Black;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25%;
    height: 10%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```